# How to use Blender's dynamic sky add-on?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

How do I use the dynamic sky add-on to create a:

**1** daytime sky with no cloud?

**2** night-time sky with stars?

**3** sunset sky with clouds?

I'll be using the cycles render engine.
Also are there any other things I need to know about the add-on?

**Problems Faced**

I don't know how the "sphere" that controls the light direction works

[image]

I don't know how to make it look realistic.

I don't know how to control the cloud level and horizon level.

So, I made this using your technique:

[image]
Now, I'm unable to add volumetric lighting, such that a light beam is clearly visible from the lighthouse. Also, if I were to change the camera angle, there should be God Rays visible from behind the floating rocks. And light shafts exiting the door too.

Now, the lighthouse has a spot lamp with a 20-degree cone with a brightness of 500 and the lights in the house have a brightness of 10 / 20, all light source emission shaders are connected to a blackbody output with a temperature of 1800K.

Comment: Could you tell what kind of difficulties you faced while trying to create those skies (apart from the stars, that I don't think are currently included in the add on)?

Comment: Is this a tutorial request or did you run into some problem?

Comment: @Jerryno yes and yes, it's like this I don't know how to use this addon plus    I don't know how to use that "sphere" thingy that controls the direction of the sunlight.

Comment: @Carlo I've made the necessary question edits

Comment: What do you mean by this: "I control the cloud level and horizon level."?

Comment: @LukeD whoops, that's a typo, correcting it now

Comment: Ok, so basically you want to control how high/low horizon should be? If yes I'll need to investigate it further. I'm making an answer for the rest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First go here: http://www.dragoneex.com/downloads/dynamic-skyadd-on and look at "Instruction" section. This is self-explanatory and will help with further tasks.

### Controlling sun/moon

These sphere you are referring to is nothing more then **Vector** > [Normal Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/vector/normal.html). There is a little info in docs about it so I'll quickly show you how to control sun with it in most understandable way.

[image: sun]

Simply, go to the **Top View** and this is the way you can relate to the sphere shading. If sphere is lit from the left, mesh will be lit the same way. If light will be visible at the center of the sphere, mesh will be lit from the top.

### Daytime sky without clouds

This one is the easiest one. You only need to change **Cloud Opacity** to **0**. These will hide our clouds. You can further adjust colors, brightness, etc.

**Used colors**

- Sky - #b0ecff
- Horizon - #fbeaea
- Cloud - #ffffff
- Sun - #bcbcbc

[image: daytime]

### Sunset sky with clouds

In this example colors are crucial. Darker sky, orange horizon, warmer sun light, lower **Brightness**. Also you will need to tweak **Clouds Opacity** and **Density** as needed. Don't forget to place sun near **Horizon** using tip from first paragraph.

**Used colors**

- Sky - #385179
- Horizon - #fb8648
- Cloud - #ffb9a8
- Sun - #bc9481

[image: sunset]

### Night-time sky with stars

This is where the fun begins and in this paragraph you will learn how to push this add-on to the limits. It's not the easiest way but it will give you total control over it. One thing I can't solve is moon opacity over stars. Maybe someone could help here.

**Used colors**

- Sky - #151f2e
- Horizon - #191825
- Cloud - #ffffff
- Sun - #7688a0

First as before adjust overall mood and colors. Brightness down, colors darker, cool sun/moon light. And after it...

[image: Night]

...go to the **Node Editor** and switch to **World**. This is an overview of what part of those noodles control what we can see.

[image: node]

**Stars**

[image: stars]

To make stars from clouds change bottom **Noise Texture** to **Voronoi Texture**, set **Scale** in **Mapping node** to **1** (X, Y, Z) and adjust **Color Ramp** (from Voronoi) to have "sharp" stars. Upper **Noise Texture** is controlled by **Clouds Density** value in add-on tab. This is basically "mask" for the stars/clouds. If set to 1 it will create "gaps" between them.

**Moon/Sun**

[image: moon]

In this part you can control how big sun/moon will be, and how big will be its halo. Nothing really to explain here. Slide **Color Ramp** values and change upper **Multiply Node** value.

### Horizon level

[image: horizon]

Another fairly easy setup, left values from **Color Ramps** are controlling horizon/sky/clouds height. Right (middle) ones are controlling sharpness.

### Sun color

You can change Sun color in MixRGB node showed in screenshot. You can also change blending mode to Linear Light to have stronger colors.

[image: color]

### Final thoughts

As far as last method isn't convenient one and feels more like "hacky" way to do this I think it could give you pretty much anything you need from this add-on. My advice would be - play with values, nodes, colors in Node Editor to find new ways to use it.

In a matter of making it realistic. Well. Overall lightning is ok. I don't know if it's physically correct but it's really good. One thing that's not realistic are clouds and stars and there is probably nothing you can do about it in this add-on. Of course you can create amazing procedural cloud setup and use it in a place of two Noise Textures but still they will be just 2D representation of clouds without Volume Scattering and such.

If something is not clear in my answer, please point it in the comments. It was pretty long one and something could be missed.

Comment: Ok, simple question: How do I control the overall star concentration?

Comment: Also, could provide me the color hexcodes from each of the scenes?

Comment: @Tejas I've added HEX colors, but you can easily read those values using Color Picker in software like Krita, Gimp, Photoshop or even Paint. You can control stars "patches" by Noise Texture, I've described it as "mask".

Comment: Cool! Thanks ... One question though, is it possible to add volumetric lighting ? (As in God Rays or light beams) while using this method? If so, then how would I do that?

Comment: I'll show you a raw render of my scene, can't upload it unfortunately, as it is huge

Comment: done, the scene is complex though and I do appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68403/discussion-between-luked-and-tejas).

Comment: Hey, is there any way to change the color of the sun/moon?

Comment: @Tejas check edit.

Comment: It seems like Cloud Density doesn't affect anything in v2.91.2.  I would expect there to be more or less clouds in the rendering, but I always seem to have partly cloudy.  Also odd that I can type in a value >1 into this field.