# How to create dynamic clouds?

Tags: animation, volumetrics

Specifically dense clouds that move really slowly, just fast enough to be noticeable in a 15 sec animation. They'll need to be 3d, interact with some floating buildings and reflect the sky. I found the dragoneex plugin "dynamic sky" to be great but the clouds don't move. Should I just modify it? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all go here and read this answer: [How to use Blender's dynamic sky add-on?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91248/how-to-use-blenders-dynamic-sky-add-on/93917#93917)

Go to **Node Editor** and switch to **World** mode.

In paragraph ***Night sky with stars*** (from the linked answer) you can see whole node setup for **Dynamic Sky** add-on. Find part ***Clouds/Stars*** and **Texture Mapping** node there:

[image: nodes]

Now you can animate any of the **Location** values to get clouds moving in chosen direction.