# Sunset sky for background

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I was looking for ways to make a sunset background like this one [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/05EQ9.jpg and was wondering if you had any tips for this kinda stuff. I tried using regular gradiants but it doesn't look like that at all.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91248/how-to-use-blenders-dynamic-sky-add-on/93917#93917

Answer (score 4):

One thought: use the "Sky" texture through a Color Ramp populated with colors that meet your desired aesthetic

[image: sunset glow]

[image: sunset glow node setup]