# Implementing a Night Sky with stars, the moon?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, eevee-render-engine

I am researching how to implement the night sky, and I have found this useful answer ([Stars background in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/stars-background-in-cycles)) that explains how to get the background to be filled with stars (even the milky way). I need some help with the lighting though: how can I simulate the light coming from this night sky? I could simulate the moonlight with a sun light, but how about a certain level of illumination generated by, for example, a city?

Thanks.

Comment: Or you can use a HDRI like this one: https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=night&h=satara_night

Comment: Do you have any references as to how to implement HDRI in Blender?

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91248/how-to-use-blenders-dynamic-sky-add-on/93917#93917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use HDRIs like the ones available for free at HDRI haven.

They have night skies.

Use is trivial (see below). Also they "rotate" realistically with the camera, which is harder to achieve otherwise.

Go to your World settings, click on the dot at the right of Color, choose Environment, then pick the HDRI file you downloaded. You can adjust the strength afterwards.

Assuming 2.80 (works with 2.79 though).

[image]

[image]

[image]